# Run PHP function indefinitely - run function directly after it has just finished

Tags: php

I have a PHP function which hits an API and pulls in data.
This takes around 6 hours.
Rather than playing around with cron-job timing, what I want is for the function to run directly after it has just finished.

For instance...

```
<?php
function run_for_six_hours() {
    // runs for six hours
    copy_of_the_above_function();
}

function copy_of_the_above_function() {
    // do the same thing again
    run_for_six_hours()
}
```

Would this method above work, or is there a better method?

I already have done some research and I know running PHP indefinetely isn't best practice, but for this instance we currently don't have a better option.

Comment: Why you want to restrt the function?

Comment: You should google for php deamon. but... as you said not a great idea.

Comment: *"I know running PHP indefinetely isn't best practice"* it might be a *worst practice* at this point. *"Rather than playing around with cron-job timing"* this is the solution.

Comment: Good time to point out Google's humour when searching for "recursion" :)

Comment: A php daemon, running indefinitely, may not have been best practice 5-10 years ago, but I don't see any big reason for avoiding it now.  PHP7 especially has addressed a lot of performance issues and memory optimization.

Comment: @AymDev I have written dozens of long-running PHP processes, and had very few issues. Nor is cron the right solution for something that should be running continuously, because it requires you to reinvent locks and monitoring which are solved much better by dedicated tools.

Answer (score 7):

The method you have described is *infinite recursion* - the function calls itself repeatedly (technically, what you have is "mutual recursion", because you have the extra wrapper `copy_of_the_above_function`, which isn't necessary). The problem with that is that in most languages (including PHP), each call stores its state on the stack until everything inside it returns, so you will have a stack like `run_for_six_hours -> copy_of_the_above_function -> run_for_six_hours -> copy_of_the_above_function -> run_for_six_hours -> copy_of_the_above_function -> ...` getting longer and longer. Eventually, PHP will hit a limit (either memory, or the maximum stack depth) and crash.

A much simpler method is just to put the function in an *infinite loop*:

```
while ( true ) {
    run_for_six_hours();
}
```

PHP will wait for the function to complete, run it again, and again, and again. As long as there's no memory leaks in the implementation, this will run indefinitely. You will need to disable [PHP's `max_execution_time` setting](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) by setting it to `0` (run forever).

However, if the script crashes for any reason, it won't restart until you log in and run it again. A better approach is to have a script that runs the code once, and use an external program to repeatedly run the script. [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is built for exactly this purpose - think of it as like `cron`, but instead of "run at a specified time", you say "make sure it's always running".

Answer (score 2):

Edit: use the above solution as described by IMSoP

If you are aware of the consequences and what you need to setup to get the script to run indefinitely, you can just call the same function again:

```
function run_for_six_hours() {
    // runs for six hours
    run_for_six_hours();
}
```

Comment: rember to change the `max execution time` to 0

Comment: There is actually no reason for recursion here at all, and you will eventually end up hitting either the stack limit or running out of memory.

Comment: You're right, your solution is much better for this.